# Advance filtering in HTTP GETs of ASP.NET web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I'm currently learning how to create an API in **ASP.NET web API** (I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 and .Net 6.0).
I've been fiddling around with the **HTTP GET** and I came across the following question... how can I implement easily a dynamic and advanced filtering and sorting option?

For example, let’s say my model has the fields: ID, Name, Surname, Age, Date added.
I want to be able to filter through any of those fields, and each field has their "special" querying option, for example, I can filter greater than in the date added field, but I can't do that in the name field.

Also, I want to be able to sort the data ascending or descending by a specific column or columns.

In other words, what approach should I follow to easily implement this filtering and sorting solution?

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: You can implement different GET action methods , taking in various params. GetPersonByID, GetPersonByAge, and so on.  Also, there are pacakages like [ServiceStack](https://docs.servicestack.net/), that can handle the boilerplate code for you.

Comment: It sounds like you're approaching an OData API.  There are libraries and tools which can help you implement that standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is to use OData and then in the GET methods that can you want them to be queryable you have to add above the get method the `[EnableQuery]`.

You will also have to map the OData permissions of what actions can be performed (for example a count operation can be done, or the query can be only make special filters in a specific column...)